# Uncaught TypeError: googleAuth.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-api, google-authentication

I've been running this Angular 5 app for a while with Google authentication and then this error suddenly appeared (both on prod and dev). Sign in is successful and I am getting a GoogleAuth object (I can get the user details), but then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: googleAuth.then is not a function
```

Here's the code block. _googleAuth is a service which calls init.

```
this._googleAuth.getAuth()
      .subscribe(googleAuth => {

        // TODO
        console.log('user signedIn: ', googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()); // this returns true

        const self = this;
        googleAuth.then(function() { // error occurs here
          if (googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            ...
          } 
...
```

I've updated the typings to:

"@types/gapi": "0.0.35",
"@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.47",

Here's the getAuth function (which seems to still work):

```
public getAuth(): Observable<GoogleAuth> {
        if (!this.GoogleAuth) {
            return this.googleApi.onLoad().mergeMap(() => this.loadGapiAuth());
        }
        return Observable.of(this.GoogleAuth);
    }
```

I've checked the typings and GoogleAuth.then is defined there. Why is it that I can get a GoogleAuth object but not call .then?

The Google docs for GoogleAuth.then are here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenoninit-onerror

Comment: `GoogleAuth` is a `promise`?

Comment: @connexo in the typings, GoogleAuth is defined as a singleton class. getAuth() returns a GoogleAuth object as an observable

Comment: *`gapi.auth2.init(params)` Initializes the GoogleAuth object. You must call this method before calling gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth's methods.* https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams

Comment: @connexo Yes, I mentioned that in the question. getAuth() calls init (in loadGapiAuth()) and it appears to work since I get the user details and signedIn status. However, the .then fucntion (which appears in intellisense too) is throwing the error. very strange.

Comment: Your code for `getAuth` does not look like Javascript.

Comment: @connexo Yes. It’s a TypeScript service. Thx for pointing that out. I forgot to add the TS label to the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not clear why this became an error now, but I found a possible solution. The TypeScript wrapper service was already calling .then after gapi.auth2.init, so it looks like I was calling it twice. I've removed that check and it seems to be working. I still have to run my test suite, but so far it looks promising.